# Vacuum energy: black hole evaporation and cosmology - a discrepancy?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, hawking-radiation, cosmological-constant, semiclassical

Black hole evaporation is a result of calculating the expectation value of the stress-energy tensor of the state of the vacuum in certain spacetimes and then making a plausibility argument as to the effect backreaction on the spacetime. It is generally believed that the resulting evaporation times for black holes are in good agreement with reality (though natch there is no physical evidence to test this against).

In cosmology a naive calculation of the expectation value of the stress-energy tensor of the vacuum state and it's effect on spacetime qualitatively is in agreement with reality, in as much as it predicts a positive cosmological constant, but is quantitatively absolutely hopeless in that the predicted cosmological constant is many orders larger than the observed value.

Why is is expected that calculations involving the vacuum state and its effect on spacetime are quantitatively in good agreement with reality in the first situation when it is known they are not in the second situation?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is regularized the second one isn't.